# problem with Debian dual boot

Tags: debian, windows

I'm trying to install Debian stable as a second OS. Windows 10 is already installed. During Debian installation, Grub doesn't recognize Windows 10 and tells me any already installed OS will become unaccessible if I continue the Debian installation.

Additional info:

- Mainboard is by Gigabyte (UEFI), secure boot is disabled
- Windows 10 and Debian need to share the same SSD
- Both Windows and Debian need to be encrypted (BitLocker / LUKS) - is that possible?

Comment: Since you already have a PXE (UEFI) grub is only needed to boot debian.  There is no need to run `grub-probe` to find OSes on other partitions.  It is, on the other hand, needed to tell the UEFI firmware where `grub-efi` is to boot debian.  (`grub-efi` needs to be placed on the EFI system partition).

Comment: @grochmal.  No need for grub-efi either.  An ESP already exists for Windows 10.  Add appropriate subdirectory for Debian to ESP, copy kernel and initramfs there, renaming as necessary to .efi, and use UEFI BDS to EFISTUB boot Debian.

Comment: Make sure you have your BitLocker recovery key available before modifying the existing Windows boot